# ClassNotFoundException for Jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder in Quarkus

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quarkus

I am creating custom client using JerseyClientBuilder and below is my Client builder code snippet

`JerseyClientBuilder.newBuilder.withConfig(configuration).build();`

When I am building quarkus application I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder` Exception.

Comment: Quarkus uses RESTEasy (or RESTEasy Reactive) as its JAX-RS implementation, so trying to use anything from Jersey is not gonna work. Remove any Jersey dependencies and use `quarkus-resteasy[-reactive]`. See e.g. this guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive

Comment: @Ladicek sounds like this comment should be an answer :)

Comment: @Ladicek The quarkus-resteasy doesn't support proxy authentication so I haveto create custom rest client .

Comment: This seems to be a relevant feature request: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12048 There are some links to look at for possible workarounds.